# loop through System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType enumeration

Tags: c#, loops, events, enums, trace

I'm trying to fill a combobox with values from System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType enumeration.

I've tried looping like

```
combo.Items.AddRange([Enum].GetValues(GetType(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType)))
```

but it is not posible.
Any ideas?

Comment: well you should provide more information besides stating `It's not possible` because it's possible but you are probably getting errors and you need to share what those errors are..

Comment: That is not looping...

Comment: Why would it loop? It doesn't look like you're adding a range, but a single item.

Comment: I am trying to populate a combobox With values from that enumeration.

Comment: Try changing your GetType to typeof, and change [Enum] to Enum

Comment: Didn't work.  How can I loop through items in System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.   I've tried that but I get  System.Enum is a type but it's used like a variable

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer instantiating TraceEventType:

> string[] enumValues = (new
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType().GetType().GetEnumNames());
>
> foreach (string item in enumValues)
>               {
>
> comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
>
> }